# Range Hood and or Fan extractor?

Tags: fans, range, hood

I have an old kitchen with an extractor fan on the wall near my electric stove and an old range hood on top of the stove. I am planning on putting a tile backsplash behind the stove and removing (covering the hole on the extractor fan), and replacing the old range hood with a new one. My question is: would it affect somehow if I remove the extractor? I think the range hood is enough for my small kitchen plus I don’t do much cooking. Please advise.
Thank you.

Comment: Extracting cooking fumes to the outside is preferable to only filtering and recirculating. Can you elaborate why running a pipe to the hole from the hood isn't viable/preferrable?

Comment: Is there a pipe from the vent hood leading outside? If so, and your new hood's fan will move enough air for the size kitchen you have, this sounds like a very viable option. If, as @ratchetfreak noted, you _don't_ have an actual duct for the hood, then you may want to run one to the extractor fan's duct, again making this a viable option.